# Java regex match outside bracks

Tags: java, regex

Say there is a string: `"first option<option 1/option 2/option 3>second option<option 5/option 6/option 7>selection{aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc}{eeeeee/fffff/ggggg}other string"`

Now I want to get 3 `ArrayList`

one for string inside "<>":

```
{"option 1/option 2/option 3", "option 5/option 6/option 7"}
```

one for string inside "{}":

```
{"aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc", "eeeeee/fffff/ggggg"}
```

and one for both outside <>/{} and inside <>/{}:

```
{"first option", "<option 1/option 2/option 3>", "second option", "<option 5/option 6/option 7>", "selection", "{aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc}", "other string"}.
```

I understand I can get string inside braces with code like:

```
    String Str = "first option<option 1/option 2/option 3>second option<option 5/option 6/option 7>selection{aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc}{eeeeee/fffff/ggggg}other string"`;
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
    Matcher mtchr_r = patt.matcher(Str);
    while (mtchr_r.find()){
        String ssssssss = mtchr_r.group ();
    }
```

but how to match string outside braces? and furthermore, how to get third ArrayList in order?

Comment: I think it would be a nice option to have multiple regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of `\G` (asserts that the next match starts from where the last match ends), it is possible to do this in one pass:

```
\G(?:[^<>{}]++|<(?<pointy>[^<>]++)>|\{(?<curly>[^{}]++)\})
```

A simple break down of the regex above:

```
\G                        # Must start from where last match ends
(?:
  [^<>{}]++               # Outside {} <>
  |                       # OR
  <(?<pointy>[^<>]++)>    # Capture content inside < > in group named 'pointy'
  |                       # OR
  \{(?<curly>[^{}]++)\}   # Capture content inside < > in group named 'curly'
)
```

Assuming there is no `<>` inside `<>` and there is no `{}` inside `{}`, and there is no unmatched `<>{}`, the regex above should split the string correctly.

The regex will stop at the first position where it encounters an invalid sequence, so in my example code below, I make sure that the position of the last match is at the end of the string.

Full example program (Java 7, but you can remove the named capturing group to make it run in previous versions of Java):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class SO28210525 {
    private static final Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\G(?:[^<>{}]++|<(?<pointy>[^<>]++)>|\\{(?<curly>[^{}]++)\\})");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "first option<option 1/option 2/option 3>second option<option 5/option 6/option 7>selection{aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc}{eeeeee/fffff/ggggg}other string";
        Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);

        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> curly = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> pointy = new ArrayList<String>();

        int lastIndex = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            tokens.add(matcher.group(0));

            String inCurly = matcher.group("curly");
            if (inCurly != null) {
                curly.add(inCurly);
            }

            String inPointy = matcher.group("pointy");
            if (inPointy != null) {
                pointy.add(inPointy);
            }

            lastIndex = matcher.end(0);
        }

        if (lastIndex != input.length()) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input");
        } else {

            System.out.println(tokens);
            System.out.println(curly);
            System.out.println(pointy);
        }
    }

}
```

In previous version of Java (6 and below), as an alternative, you can use `Matcher.start` or `Matcher.end` method to check whether a capturing group captures something or not.

However, in Java 7, the corresponding `Matcher.start` and `Matcher.end` methods for named capturing group are missing (only `Matcher.group` is available). The 2 methods are later added in Java 8.

Comment: I get the same result using `Pattern.compile("[^<>{}]+|<(?<pointy>[^<>]+)>|\\{(?<curly>[^{}]+)\\}")`. What does the `\\G` accomplish?

Comment: @Keppil: Force the regex to fail immediately when the input is invalid. It at least provides a mechanism to detect bad input, and not just chuck through it.

Comment: @Keppil: I match the delimiters + content inside, and set proper capturing group to capture the content inside only.

Comment: After a simple match testing in notepad++, this is very likely the correct answer. I will test it in Java later. But I still have question about how it works. What the `++` means in regex and what's the difference between `<([^<>]++)>` and `<.*?>` ?

Comment: @TRX: `[^<>]` in `<([^<>]++)>` forbids `<>` inside `<>` ; `<.*?>`, **if standalone**, may match `<` inside `<>`, but otherwise the same (if it is not standalone, then the story is different). `++` has almost the same meaning as `+`, except that it disallows backtracking. I use it here, since I can safely chucks ahead when I have explicitly disallow `>`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a regular expression that matches all cases, e.g. `(<[^>]*>)|(\{[^}]*\})|([^{<]*)` (in Java you would have to escape the `\`s)

However this doesn't allow you to distinguish between the type of match (`<...>`, `{...}` or remaining text) found. So it would probably be better to have 3 regular expressions as suggested in the comments to your question:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("(<[^>]*>)|(\\{[^}]*\\})|([^{<]*)");
```

You can then simply add all the matches to your lists.

Comment: Could you explain why `([^{<]*)` in pattern3 matches outside `<>` and `{}`? Thanks.

Comment: `[]` defines a set of characters to match. `^` inside these means "Match anything except...". So it matches as many characters as it can that are not `<` or `{` (and would denote the beginning of a different kind of group).

Comment: So why `([^{<]*)` does not match something inside `<>`?

Comment: Simply put, because regular expressions consider a string from left to right and if a `<` had been found then `(<[^>]*>)` would match that bit, so `([^{<]*)` will not match inside a `<>` as long as the other option is available. If you're interested in the theory behind it, I think reading up on the connection to regular languages would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the third one, one regex only isn't the right way to go. I'd recommend to make three different patterns for your three arrays.:

```
String Str = "first option<option 1/option 2/option 3>second option<option 5/option 6/option 7>selection{aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc}{eeeeee/fffff/ggggg}other string";
        Pattern inside = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
        Pattern insideBrackets = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}");
        Pattern inAndOutside = Pattern.compile("(<[^>]*>)|(\\{[^}]*\\})|([^{<]*)");
        Matcher matcher1 = inside.matcher(Str);
        Matcher matcher2 = insideBrackets.matcher(Str);
        Matcher matcher3 = inAndOutside.matcher(Str);
        ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> array3 = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher1.find()) {
            array1.add(matcher1.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
            found = true;
        }

        while (matcher2.find()) {
            array2.add(matcher2.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
            found = true;
        }

        while (matcher3.find()) {
            array3.add(matcher3.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher3.group(1));
            found = true;
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("No match found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain why `([^{<]*)` in `inAndOutside` matches outside `<...>` and `{...}`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)|(?<={)[^}]*(?=})
```

You can use this to get both strings inside `<>` and `{}`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/19

Use this to get all separately including those outside.

```
(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)|(?<={)[^}]*(?=})|[^<>{}]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/20